# Exact constraint search in marklogic8

Tags: xquery, marklogic, marklogic-8

Two different documents in my database (with default index setup) contains title like below

first document:-

```
   <title>Reconceptualizing Subject</title>
```

second document:-

```
<title>Reconceptualizing Subject (LP)</title>
```

I have created word constraint on title for search in the title

```
  <constraint name="title">
    <word>
      <element ns="" name="title"/>
      <term-option>case-insensitive</term-option>
     </word>
  </constraint>
```

so if I query search:search("title:Reconceptualizing Subject") then I am getting both document as a result from database but if I query search:search("title:Reconceptualizing Subject (LP)") it gives me only single document result.

How can I achieve exact search (single document) when I query "title:Reconceptualizing Subject" ?

Answer (score 2):

Change your search constraint to:

```
<constraint name="title">
  <value>
    <element ns="" name="title"/>
    <term-option>case-insensitive</term-option>
  </value>
</constraint>
```

And then double-quote your search string:

```
search:search(' title:"Reconceptualizing Subject" ')
```

HTH!

Comment: Thanks @Geert for quick suggestion but try changing title from word to value constraint and code in search:search('title:"Reconceptualizing Subject" ', $options, 1, 20) but I am not getting result  <search:response snippet-format="snippet" total="0" start="1" page-length="20" xmlns:search="http://marklogic.com/appservices/search">
<search:qtext>title:"Reconceptualizing Subject" </search:qtext>
<search:metrics>
<search:query-resolution-time>PT0.003S</search:query-resolution-time>
<search:total-time>PT0.004S</search:total-time>
</search:metrics>
</search:response>

Comment: try search:search("title:Reconceptualizing Subject"), this.